# What interpolation methods can I use to get the tightest fit for these curves?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

I am working with MRI images of the brain that have certain areas marked by hand like [image: this] and [image: this].

I am trying to come up with an interpolating function that will let me describe such curves so that I can use machine learning techniques to automatically generate such markings on unmarked images like [image: this] and [image: this].

I've considered using cubic spline interpolations to approximate the curve, but as far as I know, I would have to split the curve into multiple parts to interpolate it.

Am I on the right track or are there other (better?) ways to do this?

Comment: @rdaszy, you might want to check this Matlab example: http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexcell.html

Comment: There is a toolbox for image fitting: http://www.mathworks.es/products/curvefitting/ You can find some examples here: http://www.mathworks.es/support/tech-notes/1500/1508.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a time series of images, I recommend the [CONDENSATION algorithm](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~misard/condensation.html) for the interpolation of curves (see also the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_algorithm)). There are a number of implementation available, notably in [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cvcondensation).